# Surrounding with try/catch an access instead of checking for null?

Tags: java, exception, null

I've been working on a codebase in which the following structure is quite common:

```
String value = null;

try {
    value = pojoClass.getValue().getANumberOfFunctions();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //ignore
}

if (value != null) {
    //stuff going on
}
```

Just to point out: The surrounded code would only throw an exception if the pojo or any of its nested objects is null. There's no database access inside or anything else more complex than a chain of "get" functions.

For what I know, throwing an exception is more expensive in performance terms than doing several null checkings. I can understand (up to a certain point) doing this if there are several objects that could being null for simplicity's sake (Although not for debug's sake), but usually the code I've seen comprises several lines of initializations, try/catches that could easily go into a simple if statement (as usually "else" means do nothing).

Am I missing something, is this "lazy programming", there's something going on above my understanding here?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty lazy.

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: *"For what I know, throwing an exception is more expensive in performance terms"* even if that was true: never choose any syntax or style for performance considerations unless you have **proven by measurement** that there is a performance issue at all **and** the chosen syntax/style *really solves it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you presented is simply bad code, a variant of *odd ball solution*:
The same problem (here check for `null`) is solved in different ways.

You should stick with one version only.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8, I'd recommend using the [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class. It allows you to do something conditionally depending if object is present(not null) or not in a one line way. Example:

```
static class A {    
    private B b;
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }   
    public B getB() {return b;}
}

static class B {
    private String s;
    public B(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a1 = new A(new B("a1"));
    A a2 = new A(null);

    Optional.ofNullable(a1).map(A::getB).map(B::getS).ifPresent(s->{
        System.out.println(s);
    });

    Optional.ofNullable(a2).map(A::getB).map(B::getS).ifPresent(s->{
        //this won't be executed
        System.out.println(s);
    });
}
```